# Breakpoint issue in async requests

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I ran into a problem with breakpoints:

when I put breakpoints in any place in code which run in background thread Android Studio show crossed white circle and this breakpoint doesn't work.
I tried to "play" with breakpoint parameters (in case if studio bug in parameters) but it not helped. 
It's looks like this problem occur only when I put breakpoint in async code like Rx or LiveData.

Is anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of problem was

```
minifyEnabled true
```

in Gradle debug configuration

I set in to false and now breakpoints work as expected

Answer (score 0):

My cat walked on the keyboard and he turned on this mode somehow.

**To fix it I just clicked the "Mute Breakpoints" button in the debugger window.**

[image]